# Activate different TabItem when another TabItem is active

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a TabControl with several TabItems. I have a Button which, when pressed, shows the TabControl in my application and opens a specific tab. This works when I am somewhere in my application where the TabControl is not visible. However, when the TabControl is visible and a different tab is selected, the Button does not work. The tab does not change.

Here is what my TabControl looks like

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
    <TabItem Header="Log"/>
    <TabItem x:Name="AlarmTab" Header="Alarms"/>
</TabControl>
```

I tried the following three approaches in the Button command

```
TabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
TabControl.SelectedItem = AlarmTab;
AlarmTab.IsSelected = true;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => AlarmTab.IsSelected = true);
```

however none of these work when another tab is selected.

**EDIT:**

It works when I am using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke, but I don't think I should use BeginInvoke because then it could happen that I am seeing the TabControl before the other tab has been switched to, right?